# Fallout 3 - No Disk Inserted Error

Tags: fallout-3, windows

I cannot play Fallout 3. Whenever I click either the Fallout3.exe or falloutlauncher.exe and this message appears:

> No disc inserted.     Please insert the original "Fallout 3" CD/DVD.
>   Please have a look at http://www.securom.com/message.asp?m=nodisc for
>   further, more detailed information.

I've seen many people saying that you don't need the disk to play because you can just click the fallout3.exe but I still get this message.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Does this happen even when you have your Fallout 3 game disc inserted, or are you trying to use a pirated version of the game?

Comment: @Alain I have the official Version and it cannot seem to see it.

Comment: @Ginger Bill  You cannot seem to see what? Is your game disc inserted when this message appears or not?

Comment: @Alain Sorry I wasn't clear. What I mean is that I have the disc inserted and it does not matter which executable file I click, it still brings up the error message even though the disc is in the drive

Comment: Have you tried right clicking the disc drive and choosing "Autolaunch" to see what the game does?

Comment: @Ginger Bill Try getting a cracked EXE. If you use a official version, I don't think there's a problem. I did that with my copy and it worked.

Answer (score 4):

Only certain versions have been able to get away with playing without the disc. Bethisda released an official Fallout 3 patch (1.7) which is supposed to remove the need for the CD and get rid of that error.

Go to http://fallout.bethsoft.com/eng/downloads/updates.php. (You might need to specify your age first, and then reload the above URL) and download and install the patch, see if it solves the problem.

[image: Patch]

Comment: Oh, nice. I guess there is a reason to patch after all. Thanks for the info

Comment: Actually I have done this and still no luck.

Comment: Probably a corrupt install then. I'd remove the whole thing, re-install, and re-patch.